# React Hooks populate array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Scenario: I have an array of objects to populate a list. When the user clicks on one of the items, that item needs to be come "selected" visually and what I would think is pushed to a new array called "selectedList". If the user clicks on another unselected item that becomes selected and also maintaining the previous selection. If the user clicks on a selected item it needs to toggle the selected state to unselected and remove within the selectedList array.

My thinking on this is to have a selectedList array which consists of the default object added first, then as the user clicks on other objects, push them into the array. I have this so far.

How can I toggle the selection within the array and how can I check the selectedList array so I can tell the "FundCard" component to set it's selected state to true so it visually updates to a selected state?

Here's what I have so far:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import FundCard from '../FundCard'

const FundDLWrap = styled.ul`
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
  margin-top: -40px;
  height: 1007px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  li {
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
`

const FundDetailList = ({data, fundID}) => {
  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState([fundID]);

  const listSelection = (i) => {
    setSelectedList([...selectedList, i]);
  }

  console.log("selected list", selectedList);

  return (
    <FundDLWrap>
      {data.map((item, i) => {
        // one item must always be selected - the item ID the user came from 
        const selected = fundID === i;

        return (
          <li key={i} onClick={() => listSelection(i)}>
            <FundCard data={item} vertical={true} selected={selected} />
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </FundDLWrap>
  )
}

export default FundDetailList;
```

here's what one of the data objects look like:

```js
{
    saved: false,
    name: 'Title here',
    dailyChange: "3.52",
    inc: true,
    price: '132.42',
    priceDate: '11 Mar 2020',
    volRating: 1,
  },
```

please note the data is external and is not kept in state.

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using codepen or codesandbox to show the issue happening.

Comment: Isn't the only thing you need to do is the check if the index is in the list in your handler and then either filter it out or push it in? e.g. `setSelectedList(selectedList.includes(i) ? selectedList.filter(j => j !== i) : [... selectedList, i])`

Comment: @TomFinney This is great! Yes that's one portion of it. I need to then to be able to check the selectedList for active items so I can set the FundCard to be active - see the FundCard component for the selected prop - this sets them "selected" visually.

Comment: You can just use the same logic from the handler like `selected={selectedList.includes(i)}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the specified index `i` is in the `selectedList` then filter it out, otherwise, append it to a copy of the array.

Use the same `selectedList.includes(i)` check in the return to set the `selected` prop of `FundCard`.

```
const FundDetailList = ({data, fundID}) => {
  // Don't populate index 0 with fundID, it'll get matched in the map function
  const [selectedList, setSelectedList] = useState([]);

  const listSelection = (i) => {
    setSelectedList(
      selectedList.includes(i) 
        ? selectedList.filter(index => index !== i) 
        : [... selectedList, i]
    );
  }

  return (
    <FundDLWrap>
      {data.map((item, i) => {
        // one item must always be selected - the item ID the user came from 
        const selected = selectedList.includes(i) || fundID === i;

        return (
          <li key={i} onClick={() => listSelection(i)}>
            <FundCard data={item} vertical selected={selected} />
          </li>
        );
      })}
    </FundDLWrap>
  )
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note - I'm having trouble with the selectedList.includes(i) for the selected variable. The first item in the list is always selected as the fundID sets the 0 position within the selectedList array. The fundID can be any number from 0 - 9. fundID sets the first original position. any thoughts on how to solve this?

Comment: I think *not* pre-populating the `selectedList` with `fundID` would work, then the index `i` of the data mapping can match up with the index passed to the onClick callback, the check `fundID === i` is then also just an additional condition. This way `fundID` isn't coupled to any index within `selectedList`.